# ML algorithm to determine the likelihood of one value

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, likelihood

I’m a noob in machine learning algorithm. I have two possible outcome: hand and foot. I have a ratio computed based on different characteristics. For instance, the ratio can be 0.3 : 0.7
With this ratio, what kind of machine learning algorithm should I use to determine the likelihood of the picture being hand. I thought about using logistics regression or another type of classifier, but I am not sure how to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you'll just use the `ratio` of some kind (e.g. ratio of vertical and horizontal dimensions in an image) to predict if the object is an `hand` or `foot`. With just looking at one variable, your algorithms will do nothing but thresholding. Logistic regression, SVM, or one-level decision trees try to achieve this.